# Strangely encoded url

Tags: encoding, urlencode, string-decoding

**Background:**

I have been troubled by the following problem for the last week.
Normally webpages encrypt urls using base64, so that ***http://stackoverflow.com*** becomes ***aHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29t*** and it's used like this:
http://www.mysite.com/redir.php?url=**aHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29t**

**Problem:**

There are pages that use a different encryption of urls I can't crack. They all start with ***o5o4m4p4b434s2q43626z3*** and I assume that's for ***http://www.*** comparing different links of this kind.

The urls are like this: http://www.site.com/z.php?url=o5o4m4p4b434s2q43626z3... and they all redirect to an other site.

**Research:**

I have googled for different ways to encrypt/decrypt urls and text, and data and nothing.
I also googled for "o5o4m4p4b434s2q43626z3" and I got no results. Am I the only one asking how they encode it? =)

Any ideas? How does "http://www." become "o5o4m4p4b434s2q43626z3" ?

Cheers and good hunting!

Comment: Can you give more/longer examples?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some type of ID that is generated for that URL.  Most likely there is a relationship in some type of database that stores both the URL and the code there.  When redir.php is loaded, the string inside the url query string is looked up in the database and the user is redirected.